# Is it necessary to autowire session factory in DAO layer if i am using hibernate transaction manager with session factory set in its property?

Tags: spring, sessionfactory

Is it necessary to autowire session factory in dao layer if i am using hibernate transcation manager with session factory set in its property?

Here is my xml config for session factory and transaction manager. You can see that i set session factory in hibernate transaction manager property:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory"  ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Here is my code in dao layer. You can see here that i am injecting an instance of session factory,so my question is, is this necessary? or the transaction manager config is enough? thank you!

```
@Autowired
@Required
@Override
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: If you don't inject it then how do you expect to get the `SessionFactory` and be able to use hibernate from your dao?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Then what is the use of injecting the session factory in my transaction manager? thanks!

Comment: The transactiona manager is responsible for starting a transaction (and bind a session to the current thread). How is that supposed to work if you don't inject tht `SessionFactory`.... Transactions and sessions are different things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!